# simple responsive div in the middle of the screen with 3\8 width\ height ratio

Tags: html, responsive-design, scale

Well, I'm totally clueless about this.
I've spent 2 days now on trying to create this seemingly easy task

I would like to create a calculator-like widget (not really but really close to calculator)
I would like a black colored div that maintains a 3/8 width/height ratio of the visible screen.
the div should be centered.
and if the user changes the screen (by drag and drop \ full screen) the widget should adjust itself accordingly.

I cant seem to make this div work!

My intention is after i have such a div to insert a lot of nested divs inside it (like buttons)
and that they will maintain their scale accordingly.

is this task so complex?

is this task so complex i should use a framework for it? (i mean this is a simple calculator like widget why do i need a framework for that>?)

EDIT 2 
Thank you guys but i made a mistake.. what i really mean is that the widget will maintain a fixed size (width\height) of 3/8

Comment: **What have you tried**?

Comment: pure html so far, and the closest i could achieve was the code Adam posted: http://jsfiddle.net/XEnGU/1/    this code lacks one thing, it doesnt keep aspect ratio of width/height of 3/8

Comment: Do you want it center vertically and horizontally?

Comment: ok, i want this http://jsfiddle.net/5tzk3/10/   with vertical resize effect exactly like the horizontal resize effect. (this link is exactly what i need but it fails the vertical resizing with ratio. horizontal resizing is perfect in this link)

Answer (score 1):

```
#centered { 
   position: fixed; 
   top: 10%; 
   bottom: 10%; 
   width: 30%; 
   left:0; 
   right:0; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
   background: #000; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XEnGU/1/

Comment: When i drag and reduce size vertically the div is no longer 30% in width and 80% in height.  your code starts with a 80% 30% rectanle scale but i can manage to make it a square when i reduce size vertically

Comment: Yes it is - 80% is a percent, not a fixed number of pixels. It is always 30% of the window width (whatever that width is) and 80% of the window height (whatever that height is).

Comment: Oh, so i probably meant something else, pretty please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my first answer failed because your question was incorrectly worded.

In any case, here's the real answer:

To maintain a given aspect ratio using CSS, the trick is to create a 0 height container and then use padding-top.

For example, a 16:9 container would be

```
{ height:0; padding-top: 56.25%; /* 9/16 = 56.25 */ }
```

So, you can correctly guess than that a 8:3 ratio would be 37.5% (3/8).

Knowing that information, and some other CSS magic, I threw together the following fiddle.
This stays in the center of the screen and maintains aspect ratio.

http://jsfiddle.net/k7Cj6/2/

Keep in mind the danger of maintaining an aspect ratio is that the content can now easily overflow the element.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HT6cw/) for you one jsFiddle. Its scaleable in the x and in the y-axis.

```
  #content{
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    bottom:10%;
    right:35%;
    left:35%;
    background:black;
  }
```

Comment: again, this solution worked for my erroneous original post, please see my edit for the correction of what i need. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a script I wrote:

https://github.com/AwokeKnowing/responsivem

you can say

```
responsivem(300,800)
```

then set your main div to

```
style="width:300em; height:800em"
```

and so a button that is 1/3 the width of the app would be width:100em.  See the demo and try it out!!